# MSTest unit test on .NET Core only provides seven encodings. How can I reach the ANSI one?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, character-encoding, visual-studio-2022

I'm unit testing a .NET Core solution in Visual Studio 2022 on Windows.

In my solution I want to output an ANSI string stored in a byte buffer, but that doesn't seem to work.

This is an extract of the byte buffer:

```cs
byte[] test = new byte[] {65, 32, 150, 32, 66};
```

The text to extract is: `A – B`.

This is what I tried so far:

```cs
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

A ? B


Encoding.Latin1.GetString(buffer);

A \u0096 B


Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

A � B


Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);


Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(buffer)
'Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(buffer)' raised an exception of type'System.NotSupportedException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233067
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method."
    Source: "System.Private.CoreLib"
    StackTrace: "   bei System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32 codepage)"
    TargetSite: {System.Text.Encoding GetEncoding(Int32)}
```

Only the following code pages are available while I'm running the Visual Studio 2022 debugger:

```cs
Encoding.GetEncodings().Length

7
```

| Code Page | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | utf-16 |
| 1201 | utf-16BE |
| 12000 | utf-32 |
| 12001 | utf-32BE |
| 20127 | us-ascii |
| 28591 | iso-8859-1 |
| 65001 | utf-8 |

How can I correctly decode the above text?

Comment: Weird. Should be `28591 iso-8859-1` instead of `1200 iso-8859-1`?

Comment: @JosefZ: Oh, yes … Pardon me! Ich updated my question now.